# Black Bar on Images Above 1/2000 Canon XSi

Tags: shutter-speed, canon-450d, shutter-priority

Has anyone ever had this happen on any camera/lens/setup? From what I've googled, could be a shutter failing to close fast enough.

[Broken Images Link](https://picasaweb.google.com/110220062892008863644/ShutterProblems?authkey=Gv1sRgCPbfqafS4uKxqQE) - I have the test shots from after the game at home I can upload later today.   The 1st two pictures here are 1/3200, the 3rd picture is 1/2000.

Taking some pictures at a youth baseball game over the weekend, I noticed this black bar showing at the top of the image.  At first I wasn't sure what might be causing it, it takes up about an 1/8th of the image.   Turning the camera sideways for a portrait shot, the image shows on the right side of the image, just as it did on the top during landscape, so it seems to be same part of camera.

When I got home, I took some test shots, and it appears after 1/2000 of a second shutter speed priority, is when I'd start to see this image creep.   The xsi goes to 1/4000 and when I step my shutter through from 1/2000 to 1/4000 the image gets darker and larger.

At some point during shooting in the baseball game, I did get a Cannon Error Code 99, which as I understand might be a catch all code for, turn-off and back on and if it continues, contact cannon service professional.   A quick poke on canon's site shows that I might end up paying around $203 to fix the XSi.

Is there anything that can help me confirm on my own that my shutter might be closing too slowly?  At $203 I'm not sure I'd get it repaired but just get a new body.   Although I just purchased an EF 70-200mm f/2.8 so I don't really have the funds to buy more than the Rebel series, which I was planning on going to a higher-end Canon after I saved up more money.  So I'd like to extend the life of this XSi a bit longer of possible.

Comment: Could you post some example photos please? Might help with diagnosing the issue.

Comment: In addition to @NickMiners's comment, if you don't have enough rep to post pictures directly, post them somewhere and edit links into your question and someone will edit them into the question directly.

Comment: Added a link.   Will post my test shots this evening to show the steps from 1/2000 on up.   Thanks.

Comment: Hi Eric, if you really think this is a different question, let me know, but I think this is the same. It struck me because I knew I had answered this once...

Comment: I'd say the answer you linked to is accurate to the problem I'm having, so I would say this is a duplicate.  I did try searching for it first but did not get to that post for some reason.  Thanks.

Comment: I just uploaded more test shots.  I took a shot in live mode too at 1/4000 and it came out fine?  I'm going to try a few more in live mode to confirm the results are better in live mode than in viewfinder only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It certainly sounds like the shutter is your problem from what you describe.  The fact that it changes with shutter rate doesn't leave a lot of other options unless you are using flash photography.

If you are doing flash photography, it could also be an issue with HSS (high speed sync).  With HSS, the flash goes off multiple times as the shutter travels and if it was starting late, it wouldn't expose the first few portions of the image.

Similarly, if it is the shutter moving too slowly, then it is probably a dying shutter.  If you've used the camera quite a bit, it's pretty likely that this could be the problem.  Shutters don't last forever and while I couldn't find official estimates of shutter life for the xTi, but they seem to be around 50,000 to 150,000.

As far as if it is worth sending in or just buying a new body, it's really up to you.  Like you said, on the one hand the xTi is a fairly old body now, but if you really want to move up in quality, spending an extra $600 to $650 that is really just going to be a waste in the long run isn't gonna help much either.  Yes, the current Rebels are far superior to the xTi, but if you are looking to get something better, is it really worth upgrading now?